# Computer sleeping immediately after screen despite being set to sleep later

Tags: catalina, sleep-wake, power, power-management, pmset

My current `pmset -g` is the following:

```
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 lidwake              1
 autopoweroff         1
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 autopoweroffdelay    259200
 proximitywake        1
 standby              1
 standbydelaylow      10800
 ttyskeepawake        1
 hibernatemode        3
 powernap             0
 gpuswitch            2
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 highstandbythreshold 50
 displaysleep         1
 sleep                10
 acwake               0
 halfdim              1
 tcpkeepalive         1
 disksleep            10
```

I've set the following:

```
displaysleep         1
sleep                10
```

Based on the man page for `pmset`:

```
displaysleep - display sleep timer; replaces 'dim' argument in 10.4 (value in minutes, or
     0 to disable)
```

and

```
sleep - system sleep timer (value in minutes, or 0 to disable)
```

One would think they're both separated (ie: Sleep the display first, then the computer); [however this is the behaviour when set as described above (video)](https://i.imgur.com/jbFOZoW.mp4)
Basically, the screen dims at around 60 secs, sometimes over 100 secs, and then a few seconds later the computer goes to sleep, despite both being set far apart (screen: 1min --- Computer: 10 mins)

None of the `pmset -g log`(s) spits out any useful output when this even occurs (at least none that I can identify). But in case anything helps:

- [Output for pmset -g log (pastebin)](https://pastebin.run/szspsgj9zr3w.txt) from the time the display dimmed and computer slept

If anyone can lead me from here to my goal of being able to set the screen to dim after x mins and then the computer to sleep after x*2 mins. Thank you!